# Deleting an element from one-to-many collection (Java + HIbernate + Struts)

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, struts

I can't delete a child object from the database.  From the `org.apache.struts.action.Action.execute()` method, I am removing the child from the parent's `List`, and also calling `session.delete(child)`.  I've simplified the code below and only included what I believe to be relavent.

### Hibernate Mapping

```
<class 
    name="xxx.xxx.hibernate.Parent" 
    table="parent">

    ...

    <list
        name="children"
        cascade="all,delete-orphan"
        lazy="true"
        inverse="true">

        <key column="parent_id"/>
        <index column="list_index"/>
        <one-to-many class="xxx.xxx.hibernate.Child"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class 
    name="xxx.xxx.hibernate.Child" 
    table="child">

    ...

    <many-to-one
        name="parent"
        class="xxx.xxx.hibernate.Parent"
        not-null="true"
        column="parent_id" />

</class>
```

### Excerpt from execute() method

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();  //session is of type org.hibernate.Session

try {
    Parent parent = (Parent) session.get(Parent.class, getParentId());

    Iterator i = form.getDeleteItems().iterator();  //form is of type org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Child child = (Child) i.next();
        session.delete(child);
        parent.getChildren().remove(child); //getChildren() returns type java.util.List
    }

    session.saveOrUpdate(parent);
    tx.commit();
} ...
```

I've tried with only `session.delete(child);` and I've tried with only `parent.getChildren().remove(child);` and with both lines, all without success.  There are no errors or thrown exceptions or anything of the sort.  I'm sure this code gets called (I've even used `System.out.println();` to trace what's happening), but the database isn't updated.    I can add children using similar code, edit non-collection properties of existing children, edit the parent's properties, all of that works, just not deleting!

According to the [Hibernate FAQ](https://www.hibernate.org/116.html#A18) I'm doing the mapping right, and according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289033/deleting-thing-a-in-hibernate-does-not-update-objects-with-collections-of-a) I've got the right logic.  I've looked all over the internet and can't seem to find anything else.

What am I doing wrong?  Please help!  Thanks.

### Notes on versions

Everything is a few years old:

- Java 1.4.2
- SQL Server 2005
- Hibernate 3.0.5
- Struts 1.2.7
- Apache Tomcat 5.0.28

Comment: Did you override equals/hashcode properly in Child? Did you verify that the Child is removed from Parent after calling remove()? If it isn't you may actually undoing the delete action. It should be enough to remove the child from the parent list and update the parent (this will cause the list_index to be updated as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't overridden the `equals()` method, the entity is probably not found in the list, because it has been detached, and is now a different instance. That's why the `remove` isn't working. Then even if the `delete` works, the objects are re-cascacde because they still exist in the collection. Here's what to do:

- either override the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method(s), using either the `id` (easy) or some sort of busines key (more appropriate) (search stackoverflow for tips for overrideing these two metods), and leave only `getChildren().remove(child)`
- Iterate over the collection of children in the first loop, like this:

  ```
  Iterator<Child> i = form.getDeleteItems().iterator();
  while(i.hasNext()){
      Child child = i.next();
      for (Iterator<Child> it = parent.getChildren().iterator();) {
           if (child.getId().equals(it.next().getId()) {
               it.remove(); // this removes the child from the underlying collection
           }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: it won't work even after overriding equals and hashCode. Removing the object via the iterator is not nessesary, remove does the same faster.

Comment: why do you think so? I think you are wrong in both statements :)

Comment: Is the Child's Id populated properly in the Form?

Comment: @Bozho: Unfortunately, I didn't have a chance to try it yet. I have been putting out other fires all day at work. I will probably try it on the weekend, or early next week. Don't worry, once I try out some things I'll up vote and select an answer.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response, but I'm the only one on the team (for development and support!) and sometimes it gets pretty crazy.  Thanks so much, this helped a lot. I ended up also having to change the way getDeletedItems was filled, and a few other things, but in the end this basic technique did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes this behavior in hibernate, you can get going by loading the `Child` first. Separately deleting the `Child` is not nessesary. Updated code should look like;

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();  //session is of type org.hibernate.Session

try {
    Parent parent = (Parent) session.get(Parent.class, getParentId());

    Iterator i = form.getDeleteItems().iterator();  //form is of type org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Child child = (Child) session.get(Chile.class, ((Child) i.next()).getChildId());
        parent.getChildren().remove(child); //getChildren() returns type java.util.List
    }

    session.saveOrUpdate(parent);
    tx.commit();
} ...
```

show the SQL generated by Hibernate

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

**Edit:**

Check out this [Chapter 10. Working with objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached)

Comment: this will work, but I think loading each object anew should be avoided.

Comment: @Bozho: Why do you think loading each object anew should be avoided? What makes your solution better than this?

Comment: if the session is fresh, this would mean N queries to the database for fetching the items.

Answer (score -2):

In this case, the Child class is the owner of the inverse relation, Hibernate will look at the parent reference of the child to determine whether the relation is still there. Since you don't set the parent to null, the relation exists and the child may not be deleted. Try doing

```
parent.getChildren().remove(child);
child.parent = null; 
session.delete(child);
```

Also remove the not-null="true" from the parent property mapping.

The best thing to do when working with inverse associations, is to update both sides in Java code, that way you can continue working with the objects in memory and you don't have to worry about which side owns the relation.

A similar situation is discussed here: http://simoes.org/docs/hibernate-2.1/155.html

Comment: Delete orphan will handle the removal of child even if you omit the 2nd line. And this won't work because remove(child) won't remove anything

Comment: Indeed, I thought that inverse="true" would prevent the removal, but http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html states that cascades are still processed when inverse="true".